# Kubernetes env referencing a tls crt and key

Tags: kubernetes, ssl, tls1.2

I have been trying to port over some infrastructure to K8S from a VM docker setup. But I cannot seem to reference the tls certificate and key properly within the K8S `env.yaml` such that the container using the `env` can use them correctly.

In a traditional VM docker setup the `.env` file looks like this for referencing the tls cert+key:

```
TLS_CERT_PATH=/tls/server.crt
TLS_KEY_PATH=/tls/server.key
```

In my K8S I create the tls cert+key via:

```
kubectl create secret tls cl-tls --key "server.key" --cert "server.crt"
```

And I reference the tls cert+key via within the `env-configmap.yaml` via:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: env-config
data:
  TLS_CERT_PATH: "cl-tls"
  TLS_KEY_PATH: "cl-tls"
```

I have additionally tried with no luck either:

```
kubectl create secret generic tls-cert --from-file="server.crt"
kubectl create secret generic tls-key --from-file="server.key"
```

With a `env-configmap.yaml`:

```
TLS_CERT_PATH: "tls-cert"
TLS_KEY_PATH: "tls-key"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing two different concepts.

1. You want to make the `server.key` and `server.cert` files available to your pods, and want to reference them in your pod specification in the form of `PATH` variables. This is a separate implementation.       ***LEGACY APPROACH***
2. You want to convert the `server.key` and `server.cert` to a `secret` object. And you want to use the `secret` in your pods to inject the `server.key` and `server.cert` information directly in the pod. ***KUBERNETES NATIVE APPROACH***

> Note: You do not need a `ConfigMap` in any case. (You should never use `ConfigMap` type for sensitive data anyway).

### Procedure for Approach 1

1. Put the `server.cert` and `server.key` in a directory on the worker node where your pod will run. Let's call it `~/certs/`.
2. Mount this directory as a volume to your pods, with type `hostPath`. You can read more about them [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#hostpath).
3. Add `TLS_CERT_PATH: "~/.certs/server.cert"` and `TLS_KEY_PATH: "~/.certs/server.key"` as environment variable to your pod. This will work as expected.

This is it. You do not need config maps or secrets and this approach will work. This is not a recommended approach since if you want to rotate the certificates when they are about to expire, you'll have to manually update the `server.key` and `server.cert` files on your node for the pod authentication to work. But this is how it will be done.

### Procedure for Approach 2

1. Create a `tls` type secret with your `server.cert` and `server.key` files. (You're already doing this correctly). You can use [this doc](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/#tls-secrets) for more details.
2. Use that secret to inject the `server.cert` and `server.key` into your pods. You will mount this secret as a volume to your pod. And then you can reference the secret parameters as "files" in your pod specification. When secrets are used in this way the parameter name becomes a file at the mount point, and the parameter value becomes the contents of that file. You'll configure your pod specification with environment as `TLS_CERT_PATH: "secret/mount/path/server.cert"` and `TLS_KEY_PATH:"secret/mount/path/server.key"`. You can find the recipe to do that in the docs [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/#using-secrets-as-files-from-a-pod).

Both approaches will work. Except this time, you can very easily rotate your TLS certificates by simply updating the `Secret` object and the volume mount sync will automatically update it in all the pods that have it mounted. Understand that secrets are functionally equivalent to `ConfigMaps`. Both are key/value pairs. It is just that `Secrets` have special attributes and features that make them more suitable to be used for sensitive data.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to really explain both approaches as both are valid but has different advantages, I only have been working in k8s for about a month or less. I just confirmed in testing production that both approaches work and really was missing the volume mount!